# Construct VB code based on a string containing the statements

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string, expression

What I'm trying to do this is writing a simple parser for the following case in .NET
that given a string like this :

```
If  ([1] >=60 :  50; If ([1]>=50 :  40; If ([1]>=40 : 30; If([1]>=30 : 20;0))))
```

should return one like this :

```
If  ([1] >=60) Then 
    Return 50
ElseIf ([1]>=50) Then
    Return 40
ElseIf ([1]>=40 ) Then
    Return 30
ElseIf([1]>=30 ) Then
    Return 20
Else
    Return 0
End If
```

Using split to divide the string into multiples strings first by ";" and then by ":"  and with the use of `For Each`, I have managed to do it(though not in a very elegant way)
That's why I wonder if there wouldn't be a more elaborate way of doing this, using Regex perhaps

One last thing, do you think there is a *quick* way to get all the numbers enclosed in square brackets(variable IDs) without duplicates .

For instance , given a string like :

```
   If ([3] = ‘M’ AND [4] = ‘S’ AND [5]>=1000 : 20/100 * [5]; 500)
```

I  get, let's say , an array of integers containing (3,4,5)

What's the best way to implement such things in .NET?? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated

P.S. I couldn't find a good title for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is very late, but just for the record, you can easily achieve such capture using `Regex` like this:

```
Dim input As String = "If ([3] = ‘M’ AND [40] = ‘S’ AND [5]>=1000 : 20/100 * [5]; 500)"
Dim r As Regex = New Regex("\[(\d+)\]")
Dim list As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
For Each match As Match In r.Matches(input)
    If Not list.Contains(match.Groups(1).Value) Then
        list.Add(match.Groups(1).Value)
    End If
Next

Console.WriteLine("({0})", String.Join(",", list))
```